# Как запустить приложение на Denwer?

Tags: gwt, denwer, java

Не получается запустить на Denwer. Даже стандартное приложение, которое предоставляется гуглом `Web Application Starter Project`. Выдает ошибку связи с серверной частью. Это при выключенном `app engine`. А при включенном работает, но в Denwer не переносится (перекомпилируйте). Что делать?

Comment:  1. Вы пытаетесь перемешать мухи и котлеты
 2. не ingine а engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынужден огорчить всех, кто отметился в данном топике. GWT-приложения **можно** запускать под обычным Апачем, nginx-ом или любым другим сервером, который умеет отдавать статику, *если* это GWT-приложение полностью клиентское (не ходит по протоколу GWT-RPC за данными на сервер). Причем backend (если он вам вообще нужен) для этого клиента можно писать на PHP, Ruby, Pythone, хоть на чем, если вы сможете наладить передачу данных, например в JSON.

А так план развертывания довольно простой и бесхитростный:

1. Выключите App Engine и избавьтесь от GWT-RPC.
2. Соберите ваш GWT-проект.
3. Создайте в папке, которая предназначена под сайт, папку с именем соответствующим имени GWT-приложения (напр. `myApp`).
4. Скопируйте папку(и) GWT-модуля(ей), его(их) html-файлы (напр `MyModule.html`) и ваши ресурсы из полученного war-а в созданную в п.4 папку.
5. Запускайте апач, проверяйте. URL будет примерно такой `http://localhost/myApp/MyModule.html` (в зависимости от конфигурации).

PS для предыдущих ораторов.

> Вы пытаетесь перемешать мухи и котлеты
>
> Google Web Toolkit (GWT , ˈɡwɪt) — свободный Java-фреймворк, который позволяет веб-разработчикам создавать Ajax-приложения на основе Java.
>
> Никак) запускай на apache tomcat!

Вы ведь в курсе, что GWT компилирует код на java в html + javascript?

Comment: И стоит это того? И цель какая преследуется? И откуда вы знаете, что приложение будет клиентское, разве в вопросе об этом сказано? Вы также как и "предыдущие ораторы", просто домыслили. Есть специальный плагин для Eclipse и документация по использованию GWT вот ими инадо руководствоваться. А не придумывать довольно простой и бесхитростный план.

Comment: Ну, а эклипс то тут при чем? А деплоить в production тоже на эклипсовский jetty предложите?

Вопрос был "Как запустить приложение на Denwer?", я написал как. Подходит ли это ТС или нет - решать ему.

Comment: > документация по использованию GWT вот ими и надо руководствоваться

@Sever, вы таки не поверите. В этой документации как раз [рассматривается пример приложения](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/index), которое в первой версии не требует серверной части (более того в дальнейшем рассматривается прикручивание бэкэнда на PHP) и 

>  Any server that can serve up static web pages will do just fine.

Comment: @Sever, извините, если переборщил с сарказмом. Никого не хотел задеть. Но не могу согласиться, что @Kobayashi_Maru прав )

Comment: Я и не говорю, что в документации не сказано, поэтому и посоветовал в своем ответе ознакомиться с этой самой документацией. Короче, все я пошел спать, а то я какой-то раздражительный после ночи и во всем вижу зло. :)

Comment: Я видимо тоже...)

Answer (score 1):

Denwer - это набор дистрибутивов (`Apache, PHP, MySQL, Perl` и т.д.) и, насколько я знаю, в него не входит `Java`, а в `GWT`, учитывая сказанное в Википедии:

> Google Web Toolkit (GWT , ˈɡwɪt) —
> свободный **Java-фреймворк**, который
> позволяет веб-разработчикам создавать
> Ajax-приложения на основе **Java**.
> Выпускается под лицензией Apache
> версии 2.0. GWT делает акцент на
> повторное использование и
> кросс‐браузерную совместимость.

Советую вам ознакомиться с [документацией](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted).